# How to remove a PMD rule for SOQL CRUD Operation for Setup Objects?

Tags: apex, pmd

How can I remove Apex PMD rule violation for SOQL CRUD operation for Setup objects like Profile, Groups.

I am using @SuppressWarnings right now but is there any other turn around so that I can use WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED and not fall into error while doing an operation.

Comment: If you want to disable the rule for all the classes without having to use the `@SupressWarnings` annotation on every class you could look into setting up your own [PMD ruleset](https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the [ApexCRUDViolation](https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_rules_apex_security.html#apexcrudviolation) document from PMD it is written that:

> Since Winter ‘23 (API Version 56) you can enforce user mode for database operations by using WITH USER_MODE in SOQL. This makes Apex to respect Field-level security (FLS) and object permissions of the running user. When using user mode, no violation is reported by this rule.

Thus if you run any query with `WITH USER_MODE` then it should remove the violation by default.

Something like this.
Here I used a query on Account and you can see a violation.

[image]

But if I add `USER_MODE` then the violation gets ignored.

[image]

Or even with `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED`, I dont see any violation.

[image]